# Fill table with last result

Tags: sql, postgresql, ranking

I have a table that contains the following information:

```
id | amount |   date   | customer_id
 1 |  0.00  | 11/12/17 | 1
 2 | 54.00  | 11/12/17 | 1
 3 | 60.00  | 02/12/18 | 1
 4 |  0.00  | 01/18/17 | 2
 5 | 14.00  | 03/12/17 | 2
 6 | 24.00  | 02/22/18 | 2
 7 |  0.00  | 09/12/16 | 3
 8 | 74.00  | 10/01/17 | 3
```

What I need it to look like is the following:

```
ranked_id | id | amount |   date   | customer_id
        1 |  1 |  0.00  | 11/12/17 | 1
        2 |  2 | 54.00  | 11/12/17 | 1            
        3 |  3 | 60.00  | 02/12/18 | 1
        4 |  3 | 60.00  | 02/12/18 | 1
        5 |  3 | 60.00  | 02/12/18 | 1
        6 |  3 | 60.00  | 02/12/18 | 1
        7 |  3 | 60.00  | 02/12/18 | 1
        8 |  4 |  0.00  | 01/18/17 | 2
        9 |  5 | 14.00  | 03/12/17 | 2
       10 |  6 | 24.00  | 02/22/18 | 2
       11 |  6 | 24.00  | 02/22/18 | 2
       12 |  6 | 24.00  | 02/22/18 | 2
       13 |  6 | 24.00  | 02/22/18 | 2
       14 |  6 | 24.00  | 02/22/18 | 2
       15 |  7 |  0.00  | 09/12/16 | 3
       16 |  8 | 74.00  | 10/01/17 | 3
       17 |  8 | 74.00  | 10/01/17 | 3
       18 |  8 | 74.00  | 10/01/17 | 3
       19 |  8 | 74.00  | 10/01/17 | 3
       20 |  8 | 74.00  | 10/01/17 | 3
       21 |  8 | 74.00  | 10/01/17 | 3
```

I know that there's something with partitioning and ranking (on the ranked_id), but I can't figure out how to repeat the last row 7 times.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the result?

Comment: Sure. I have to take these results and put them into 
amount_1
date_1
amount_2
date_2
...
all the way up to amount_7 & date_7

It's the only way I could think of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gordon Linoff suggested you can use the generate_series() function crossed with the distinct customer_ids to generate all the rows needed as in T1 below.  Then in T2 (also below) the row_number function is used to generate a sequential value to outer join to from t1 along with the customer_id.

From there it's just a matter of being able to get at the last value per customer_id when there is no original data to join to which is where the case statement and analytic first_value functions come in.  I couldn't get the last_value analytic function to work likely due to postgresql's lack of an ignore nulls directive, so I used first_Value with a descending sort order, and only return the analytic value when no other data exists.

```
with t1 as (
select distinct 
       dense_rank() over (order by customer_id, generate_series) ranked_id
     , customer_id
     , generate_series
  from table1
  cross join generate_series(1,7)
), t2 as (
  select row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by id) rn
       , table1.*
    from table1
)
select t1.ranked_id
     , case when t2.customer_id is not null
            then t2.id
            else  first_value(t2.id)
                 over (partition by t1.customer_id
                       order by id desc nulls last)
       end id
     , case when t2.customer_id is not null
            then t2.amount
            else  first_value(t2.amount)
                 over (partition by t1.customer_id
                       order by id desc nulls last)
       end amount
     , case when t2.customer_id is not null
            then t2.date
            else  first_value(t2.date)
                 over (partition by t1.customer_id
                       order by id desc nulls last)
       end date
     , t1.customer_id
  from t1
  left join t2
    on t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id
   and t2.id = t1.generate_series
 order by ranked_id;
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/495f6/87) demonstrating the code.

Comment: Whew, this thing is beastly but it does solve the issue that I have. I had to put modify the "ORDER BY ranked_id" to "ORDER BY id, ranked_id" to get it in the order that I wanted. 
I appreciate both you Sentinel and GordanLinoff for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can use `generate_series()` and a cross join to generate all the rows.  Then you can pick the one you want:

```
select row_number() over (order by customer_id, id) as ranking_id,
       coalesce(t.id, cid) as id, coalesce(t.amount, c.amount) as amount
       coalesce(t.date, c.date) as date, t.customer_id
from (select distinct on (customer_id) t.*
      from t
      order by customer_id, date desc
     ) c cross join
     generate_series(1, 7) g(i) left join
     (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by date) as i
      from t
     ) t
     on t.customer_id = c.customer_id and t.i = g.i;
```